# a swift questions about String and c strcpy

Tags: ios, string, swift, cstring

I want to call a c++ function in swift

```
bool getId3Info(const char * filename , char *artist , char * title  )
{
     // get the file's id3v2 tag, write info back
    strcpy(artist,(const char*) id3v2tag->artist().toCString(true));
    strcpy(title,id3v2tag->title().toCString(true));
}
```

So I write a object-c wrapper for this function:

```
-(bool) getId3Info:(const char * )filename :( const char *)artist :( const char *) title
{
    return getId3Info(filename, (char*)artist, (char*)title);
}
```

So the questions is I can only get the representation of a C string   using `cStringUsingEncoding` ,
 can not get the true buffer of a swift `String`,
  is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you can pass a `const char*` to a C function like this:

```
func foo(s: String) { s.withCString({ p in cfunction(p) }) }
```

or, to be more explicit about the type:

```
func foo(s: String) { s.withCString({ (p:UnsafePointer<CChar>) in cfunction(p) }) }
```

(i.e., p is a `UnsafePointer<CChar>`, equivalent to `const char*`)

If you want to initialize a string from a C function, you need a more complex incantation, something like this:

```
var buf = Array<CChar>(count: 1000, repeatedValue: 0);
let result = buf.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer({
        (inout ptr: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CChar>) -> String? in
    cfunction(ptr.baseAddress, ptr.count - 1)
    String.fromCString(ptr.baseAddress)
})
```

Note that the C function must leave the buffer null-terminated.  Either it needs to never modify the last byte (thus the `ptr.count - 1`, like you would call `strncpy`) or it needs to add the null terminator itself (like `snprintf`), in which case you can pass in the full buffer size.